# Scroll to the end of the background

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i have a page with a big background 1920*3500 and i used this :

```
background-image: url(Images/Background%20work/Background-Liquified-home2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

to make it auto-resize when somebody open it on a monitor with a lower resolution , the thing is that if i dont put an image or a text at the end i cant scroll to there, so i inserted an image to the end of it and it was ok, but when i switched to a monitor with a lower resolution the 1920*1080 the image was out of the background.
So, can i make it scroll just to the end of wallpaper?

Comment: unclear what your asking, but : background-position:fixed;   ?

Comment: no, its not working... so, i have a background image and i want to be able to scroll to the end of it without having anymore images or text over it

Comment: you need to set the min-height of the containing element to the height of the background then if you want to use the actual dimension of the image.

Comment: that will probably work, i`ll let you know , thank you !

Comment: so now it look like this 

body {
 background-image: url(Images/Background%20work/Background-Liquified-home3.jpg); 
}

html {
 
 background-image: url(Images/Background%20work/Background-Liquified-home2.jpg) ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 min-height: 3500px;
}

the thing is that on smaller resolutions the width is not optimezed and it cuts from the background, even if i set the width to auto

Comment: ahh sorry, background attachment fixed is the one i was tihnking of not background-position

Comment: well this is funny, now i dont have the problem with the width ...but the min-height doesnt work anymore

Comment: yeah ditch min height.

Comment: @Mortando check Parrllax Scrolling on google, in that case, if it triggers scrolling, it might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use media screen, and put the background-size:auto for lower resolution.

```
@media (min-width: 1280px) and (max-width: 1979px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

no name

*Images/Background%20work/Background-Liquified-home2.jpg*

**change**

*this is generated if a space*  `%20`

**Images/Background/Background-Liquified-home2.jpg**

```
background-image: url(Images/Background/Background-Liquified-home2.jpg);
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

Marco Pellicciotta: If you use a script, you can call the document.body.clientWidth property to get the specific width of the client browser, and dinamically change the background image.